# Upgrading jQuery version 1.4.2 to higher version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been using jquery 1.4.2. I would like to use higher versions (jquery 1.4.3, 1.5 1.6 ).
Recently jquery relased 1.6. So please let me know the changes that I need to do to upgrade version 1.4.2 to 1.6.

Comment: Use jQuery 1.6 and use console of web browsers to find errors. In Chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+I and select CONSOLE

Comment: There are release notes and changelog links under each version on the jQuery download page, yours is one of the reasons they're there for: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Actually, don't use 1.6, use 1.6.1.

In 1.6 they introduced the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function which is meant to replace [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr), in some cases.

It wound up breaking a lot of previously working code, so in 1.6.1 they allowed the use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr), as well as [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop).

See further details [here](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/).

Answer (score 2):

Probably nothing. If your script isn't too complex, just update the jQuery version and check the browser console.

***[If you would like to, check out the changes](http://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=whats+new+in+jquery+1.6&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=ShveTdHMEMfWsgahu4ncBQ)***.